# How to prefix a refence in LaTex?

Tags: latex

so I have figures like this:

```tex
\begin{figure}[h]{}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./assets/demo/identify-usecases/DomainSplitt-1.jpg}
    \caption{Identifying Domains: Match History with Filter}
    \centering
    \label{fig:domainsplitt-one}
\end{figure}
```

and I reference them like this: `\ref{fig:domainsplitt-one}`.

In the generated PFD, the images have the caption like this `Figure 4.13: Identifying Domains: Match History with Filter`. But the reference in the text only has the number `4.13`.

I have something similar for code:

```
\begin{code}
    \captionof{listing}{Custom Element listening to global custom events}
    \label{code:listening-custom-event}
    \begin{minted}{JavaScript}
```

Here, the code has the prefix `Source Code` but in the reference is only the number. The rule I use for this is

```
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Source Code}
```

So what I need is, that the reference also have this prefix in the text. Since I'm really new to latex may question is: How do I do this?

edit: here is a link with a replica:
https://github.com/adrian-goe/latex-replica

Comment: You want to use the `cleveref` package

Comment: If you would like to see an example how to use it, please make a compilable [mre] instead of all the unconnected code fragments.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work. I added a minimal reproducible to the post. could you please look at it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cleveref` package will do all the work for you:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}


% Preamble
%\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\documentclass[12pt,DIV12,BCOR0mm,twoside,openright,headings=normal,    numbers=noenddot,headsepline,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrhack}                % to avoid KOMA-Script warning
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % UTF8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}                % Postscript fonts
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,giveninits=true,maxnames=10,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Code}
\usemintedstyle{manni}

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\crefname{listing}{code}{code}
\Crefname{listing}{Code}{Code}

% Document
\begin{document}
    this is my sample text and i want to reference \cref{code:update-a-attribute} and the \cref{fig:image}
    \begin{figure}[h]{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./img.png}
        \caption{some image}
        \centering
        \label{fig:image}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{code}
        \captionof{listing}{Update a Attribute}
        \label{code:update-a-attribute}
        \begin{minted}{JavaScript}
const fragment = document.querySelector(".fragment");
fragment.setAttribute("data", 2)
        \end{minted}
    \end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(please note that you can only have one single documentclass)